# Is it possible to display the path with an Apache index listing with a custom header?

Tags: apache, directory-index

I've set up a download site using Apache's index listing feature and a custom header:

```
Options +Indexes
HeaderName /index_header.html
```

While the default header displays the path ("Index of ...") on top of the index listing, I can't find a way to display the path using a custom header.

However, when navigating through the site structure, it would be helpful to have the path displayed somewhere. Is it possible to get this done somehow?

Not counting script solutions with PHP etc., just Apache configuration.

Comment: Does this answer help - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13736936/html-directory-listing-formatting

Comment: The default view does include the path after the words "Index of:"  Like `Index of: /blog/images`.  See this screenshot https://i.stack.imgur.com/R224e.png

Comment: @StephenOstermiller You are right. I should have mentioned that I used a custom header and footer. Will update the question accordingly. Thanks!

Comment: @Kannan Sorry, no. While it does link to an excellent tutorial, I find no mention of the path.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the "Apache-way" would be to use Server-Side-Includes (SSI) (mod_includes). There does not appear to be a way to access this information with mod_autoindex, nor to output arbitrary variables (that is what SSI is for).

For example, in `.htaccess`:

```
# Enable SSI for .html files (or use .shtml files instead)
AddOutputFilter INCLUDES .html

# Parse files for SSI
Options +Indexes +IncludesNOEXEC
HeaderName /index_header.html
```

(NB: `.shtml` files are often already configured for SSI in the server config, so if you rename the header file to `.shtml` then you probably don't need the `AddOutputFilter` directive.)

In `/index_header.html`:

```
<h1>Index of <!--#echo var="REQUEST_URI" --></h1>
```

However, `REQUEST_URI` will include a trailing slash on the "directory name" eg. `/foo/bar/`, unlike the default "Index of /foo/bar", which omits the trailing slash. If you specifically want to remove the slash suffix then you could create your own environment variable in `.htaccess`. For example:

```
# Capture the directory name less the slash suffix from the URL
SetEnvIf Request_URI "^/(?:(.+)/)?$" DIRECTORY_NAME=/$1
```

Then use `DIRECTORY_NAME` in place of `REQUEST_URI` in the above SSI.

The seemingly complex regex `^/(?:(.+)/)?$` is to account for both the document root, which consists of just a single slash, and subdirectories that contain both a slash prefix and suffix. If you are only dealing with *subdirectories* then it could be marginally simplified to:

```
# Capture the subdirectory name less the slash suffix
SetEnvIf Request_URI "(.+)/$" DIRECTORY_NAME=$1
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using a **custom header**, adding a small piece of **JavaScript** to the header file should help.

For example, below JS code in the custom header will modify the `h1` tag (custom defined) to show the current URL.

```
<h1 id="path"></h1>

<script>
document.getElementById("path").innerHTML = "Index of " + window.location.href;
</script>
```

Comment: That's a good idea! However, to get the path only, it should be `window.location.pathname`. If no one comes up with a server side solution after a while, I'll accept this answer.